# Table DDL is not executed for one table in a Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, jdbc

I am trying to insert some objects in a BatchUpdate operation into the H2 Db with Spring Boot, and I am having problems doing so. The implementation does not think that the table is created. I get an error stack trace given below.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar
[INSERT INTO Expired_Chats(chat_id, username, chat_text, expiration_date) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "EXPIRED_CHATS" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Expired_Chats(chat_id, username, chat_text, expiration_date) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-196]
```

I realise that the table is not being created, but I don't know why. According to the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html), and I quote

> Spring Boot can automatically create the schema (DDL scripts) of your DataSource and initialize it (DML scripts): it loads SQL from the standard root classpath locations schema.sql and data.sql, respectively.

My `schema.sql` is given below. It attempts to create two tables `Chats` and `Expired_Chats`. Each SQL statement is on a separate line for purposes of readability.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Chats(username VARCHAR(20), chat_text VARCHAR(256), chat_id NOT NULL BIGINT, expiration_date TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY(chat_id));
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS username_index on Chats(username);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS chat_id_index on Chats(chat_id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS expiration_date_index on Chats(expiration_date);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Expired_Chats(username VARCHAR(20), chat_text VARCHAR(256), chat_id  NOT NULL BIGINT, expiration_date TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY(chat_id));
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS username_index on Expired_Chats(username);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS chat_id_index on Expired_Chats(chat_id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS expiration_date_index on Expired_Chats(expiration_date);
```

When I run my unit test in Eclipse, I see the following console log. Both `schema.sql` and `cleanup.sql` are being executed.

```
    2017-11-08 18:16:26.635  INFO 24851 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [schema.sql]
2017-11-08 18:16:26.637  INFO 24851 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [schema.sql] in 2 ms.
2017-11-08 18:16:26.639 DEBUG 24851 --- [           main] c.underarmour.assignment.ChatRecordDao   : Inserting 1 record(s) into the expired chat table.
2017-11-08 18:16:26.639 DEBUG 24851 --- [           main] c.underarmour.assignment.ChatRecordDao   : Triggering 1 batch insert(s) to expired chat table.
2017-11-08 18:16:26.651  INFO 24851 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
2017-11-08 18:16:26.723  INFO 24851 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
```

I am trying to insert data into the database using the following code. It uses Spring JDBC's Batch Update APIs.

```
  public void insertDataInExpiredTable(Set<ChatRecord> chatRecords) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("INSERT INTO Expired_Chats(chat_id, username, chat_text, expiration_date) ");
    sb.append("VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
    Instant instant = Instant.now();
    ZonedDateTime zt = instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    List<ChatRecord> allRecords = new ArrayList<>(chatRecords);
    for (int i = 0; i < allRecords.size(); i++) {
      this.jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sb.toString(), new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
          ps.setLong(1, allRecords.get(i).getChatId());
          ps.setString(2,  allRecords.get(i).getUsername());
          ps.setString(3,  allRecords.get(i).getText());
          ps.setTimestamp(4, Timestamp.from(zt.toInstant()));
        }

        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return 100;
        }
      });
    }

  }
```

My unit test configuration is as follows

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes= {ChatRecordDao.class})
@Sql(executionPhase=ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,scripts="classpath:/schema.sql")
@Sql(executionPhase=ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD,scripts="classpath:/cleanup.sql")
public class ChatRecordDaoTest {

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  private ChatRecordDao chatRecordDao;

  @Test
  public void testInsertDataInExpiredTable() throws Exception {
    ChatRecord expected = new ChatRecord();
    expected.setUsername("test");
    expected.setText("text");
    expected.setTimeout(14400);
    expected.setChatId(1L);
    Set<ChatRecord> expiredInserted = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    expiredInserted.add(expected);
    this.chatRecordDao.insertDataInExpiredTable(expiredInserted);
  }
}
```

The clean up script consists of the following statements

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Chats;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Expired_Chats;
```

Comment: Have you tried separating out your insert scripts and ddl scripts as in creating a schema.sql and data.sql?

Comment: There are no insert scripts. Insert query is being managed by Spring JDBC. I am only creating a table and indexes in schema.sql